# Adding various objects to the DOM in sequential order

Tags: jquery

I've seen how to add the same object sequentially to the DOM via here - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-sequential-list/comment-page-6

My issue is a bit more complex in that I have various form templates the user can choose from. When one of these templates is chosen, an event appends the new object, then into the database by the  id(color_1, color_2, color_3, color_4, color_5).

Ex.

"Make up to five color selections"
Object templates are three main colors, choices each with three shades of that color:
Red(cranberry, maroon, scarlet)
Green(hunter, jade, kelly)
Blue(navy, royal, periwinkle)

The form and red template for example would look like this:

```
<div class="color-container"></div>
<form action='/colors' method='post' class="form-horizontal">
<div class="red-template">      
   <p>
      <select class="red-shade input-medium">
        <option>cranberry</option>
        <option>maroon</option>
        <option>scarlet</option>
      </select>
   </p>
</div>
<div class="green-template">Green Ex</div>
<div class="blue-template">Blue Ex</div>
```

The JQuery looks like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-red').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

    $(".red-template")
      .clone()
      .show()
      .removeClass("red-template")
      .addClass("red_" + i)
      .appendTo(".color-container");
    });

    $(".red-shade")
      .removeClass(".red-shade")
      .addClass("shade_" + i);
    });

 });
</script>
```

I have the same HTML and JQuery for blue and green. If a red template gets added, I need the div class="red-template" to change to class="red_1" then the class="red-shade" to class="shade_1". If another red is chosen, "red_2" and "shade_2".

I believe the following should work:

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
$('.red-template').attr('class', 'red_' + i);
}
```

but I'm not sure where to place this code. If I place it directly after $(document), then I don't wait for the click event. If I place it after the $('.add-red'), then it won't be sequential.

Comment: you should only have one element with any unique ID. You should be using a class of color instead of an ID. Also, you can not have multiple IDs on any one element, so again, you should be using classes for color_1 et. al.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a fiddle would help us, help you.  As it stands, we are just guessing at what you problem might be.  As @Neil S mentioned, your code uses id's incorrectly (for starters).

I went and created a fiddle here to see if that's what you are looking for:
[http://jsfiddle.net/KnbYG/](http://jsfiddle.net/KnbYG/1/)

in answering your question, you loop would probably go inside the following block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('select.input-medium').on('change', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

         ***here***
      });
  });
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've never used JSfiddle, this should help me explain much better what i'm trying to accomplish. I need to sequentially count each object i'm adding. Here's a fiddle of my latest iteration - http://jsfiddle.net/53H4w/1/

Comment: Hi @csakon  there was a syntax error on your fiddle, I fixed it and displayed the counter of the item being added. http://jsfiddle.net/53H4w/4/
Let me know if this is what you are after or if I am not on the right track :)